# Unique method not working with laravel paginate

Tags: php, laravel, model

I am using laravel 7 for my project, and I am trying to display unique items from the database with pagination, but I noticed the pagination do not work with the unque method. Please how can I go around this? Below is my code:

```
        $bid = Bid::latestFirst()->get();
        $bids = $bid->unique('item_id');
        $bids->values()->paginate(10); //This is where I get the error: BadMethodCallException
                                       //Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct()` like so

```
Bid::distinct('item_id')->latestFirst()->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Have tried distinct, but still not displaying unique items.